# How to export iterated values of a function into a text file?

Tags: export

I have a 3x3 textfile `3.txt` of numerical values. Each column corresponds to a,b,c respectively. I have a function `f(d,e)` as given below.

```
<< NumericalCalculus`

SetDirectory["C:/Users/vmsha/Downloads"];

data = ReadList["3.txt", {Number, Number, Number}]

ndata = 3;

Do[a[i] = data[[i, 1]], {i, 1, ndata}]

Do[b[i] = data[[i, 2]], {i, 1, ndata}]

Do[c[i] = data[[i, 3]], {i, 1, ndata}]

Chi[d, e] := Sum[((c[i]*d) - (e*a[i]))^2/b[i]^2, {i, 1, ndata}]
```

I would like to export all values of `f(d,e)` into a separate textfile, for specific ranges of variables `d` and `e`, Could anybody help ?

Comment: The definition of `f` is incorrect, should be `f[d_, e_]`. Use `Table` to iterate over the ranges for `d` and `e`.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Sorry it was an error, actually it is Chi[d, e]. Could i obtain a textfile now ?

Comment: No, check my previous comment. The function definition is incorrect, the arguments in the definition need to be patterns, `Chi[d_, e_]`.

Comment: You can use Export["YourOutfile.txt", YourDataToExport, "Table"]

Comment: @fred85 Let me clarify. Suppose i include say `{d, -10, 10}` and `{e, -10, 10}` in the definition of my function `Chi`. I want all values of `Chi` for the given ranges d and e, to be exported to my Outfile.txt. Then, what should i write in `YourDataToExport ` part in `Export[]` ?

Comment: @Shareef when you say `{d , -10, 10}`, do you mean you want to evaluate d at these values or in the range `-10...10`?

Comment: @fred85 I mean, to export the set of all `Chi` values, in the _range_ `-10...10` for both `d` and `e`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1];
ndata = 3;
data = RandomReal[10, {ndata, ndata}]

Do[a[i] = data[[i, 1]], {i, 1, ndata}]
Do[b[i] = data[[i, 2]], {i, 1, ndata}]
Do[c[i] = data[[i, 3]], {i, 1, ndata}]

chi[d_, e_] := Sum[((c[i]*d) - (e*a[i]))^2/b[i]^2, {i, 1, ndata}]

chiValues = Table[{d, e, chi[d, e]}, {d, -10, 10}, {e, -10, 10}] // Flatten[#, 1] &

Export["chi_values.csv", chiValues // Prepend[{"d", "e", "chi"}]]
```

Comment: I have two more concerns too. If my function  ``` chi ``` consists of more than one sum, say sum[..]+sum[..]+... and now my ``` chi ``` is a function of, say 4 or 5 variables. How to flatten my results now? Also, How to get rid off the complex part of each number in my final text file ?

Comment: @Shareef The second argument of `Flatten` needs to be `number of variables - 1`. So for `4` variables `Flatten[#, 3] &`. If you just want the real part of `chi` then `Re[chi[...]]` in `Table`.